# An efficient efficient algorithm to find all possible hands for N cards? (OFC fantasyland)

Tags: algorithm, poker

**How can I find all possible poker hands for N<16 cards, in an elegant and efficient way?**

eg: Ncards(N=6): Ah, Ad, 2h, 3h, 4h, 5s

all (22+) poker hands: AhAd, Ad2h3h4h5s, Ah2h3h4h5s

Regular lookuptables do not seem to be an option, but I'd still like it to be very fast. What is the most efficient card representation (64 bits or int[], or ...) for this problem?

**context:**

I'm trying to implement [open face chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-face_Chinese_poker) poker in C++, which is easy.

There's a bonus game called fantasyland you get to play from time to time.

You get 13, 14, or 15 cards in one go. This bonusgame is trivial to 'solve' for a human player, so I'd like to have the game engine suggest a possible play. The best play would be (+/-) the play with the most bonus points.

Easily achievable, but for educational purposes, I'd like to find an elegant solution to this problem.

**brute force solution:**

```
1)find  $pokerhands=getAllPossiblePokerHands($cards) (contains overlapping combinations, eg AhAc and Ah2x3x4x5x)

2)for each $pokerhand:

 - place the hand randomly on the board
 - redefine $cards as the cards that you haven't placed on the board
 - recursively repeat 1) and 2) untill the (13card board) board is
   filled, than call getBoardRoyalties($finalboard). Store this board and  
   its points for later use.

After all combinations have been tried, find the board with highest value, this is the solution.
```

This bruteforce solutions seems the only way to solve this?

As getBoardRoyalties() is a computationally cheap function (lookup tables), and iterating can be optimized, the only question remaining:

How can I implement getAllPossiblePokerHands($cards) in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done this exercise, and yes brute force is the only way to do this.  On the plus side, you can prune large portions of the search space by observing that the hand must not be fouled.

The simplest way to do this is to use nested combination generators.  For example, if you are considering 14 cards, you might do something like:

```
foreach front in C(14,3) possible front settings:
  foreach middle in C(11,5) possible middle settings:
    if middle fouls hand:
      continue
    foreach back in C(6,5) possible back settings:
      if back fouls hand:
        continue
      metric = evaluate(front, middle, back)
```

At that point, it's up to you to determine what to do with the metric.  You could just keep all of them in memory, even most phones should have enough memory for this.  That loop should produce less than a million values, which you could sort, sift, slice, or dice.

The real work is coming up with an evaluation function which produces a good estimate of the value of the hand.  Royalty points are a good starting point, but you'll need more than that.